# Sprite Navigation Tools

Tags: css, css-sprites

**I was wondering if anyone is aware of any alternatives to tools such as [SpriteCow](http://www.spritecow.com/)?**

Sometimes i have issues with SpriteCow - namely when images tend to be very close together, it seems that it has difficulty selecting just the image you want. Those of you that have worked with complex sprite sheets which have images very close or glued together will know what i am talking about.

I was wondering if there are any other alternative or similar services that i am not aware about? Or perhaps i am not using spriteCow as well as i could? Feedback is appreciated.

Cheers,

Antonio

Comment: There's **[stiches](http://draeton.github.io/stitches/)** has yet to fail me, on a side note questions asking us to recommend tools are off topic on SO.

Comment: Thanks for that! Looks promising. Apologies then...I was under the impression that this is a forum in which people ask those with more knowledge than themselves and in the process benefit the community.

Comment: Well such questions are opinion based and tend to develop into discussions. Anyway was just giving you a heads up.

Answer (score 2):

http://spritegen.website-performance.org/ 
http://spriteme.org/

The above are the sprite generators that I frequently use. Hope this
 helps too!

In the above generators on can also set the space between the images.